# Recommend a drupal module for creating settings page for website

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

Please recommend me a Drupal module so i can create a settings page (a page of different fields for configuring website like text in home page, size of block , etc. so a simple user can change them)?

I thought the CCK could be good, but the problem with CCK is that the result is that we can create unlimited number of settings page where just one is useful, it's a way but not a clean perfect one. Please help me with your recommendations.

**Also i know i can write a custom module and use the form api!**

Regards,

Comment: may be i can wrap up my question to how to force a CCK to have a  Singleton instance , just 1

Comment: See system_settings_form() and few of its examples. Trust me it's easy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution to my problem, here's the recipe:

1) Create the desired CCK content type. (Let's call it for example Home-Page-Settings and add your desired fields to it).

2) Then create JUST one node from that content type.

3) At last for the target roles just remove the permission for **adding** and **deleting** new Home-Page-Settings  and just grant the edit access to that roles.

That's all you need to do if you had my same situation. If you have better solutions please share here and let me and other knows.

Regards